# Can you give me sources where to find examples of clojure development stacks?

Tags: clojure, architecture, clojurescript

Can someone give me examples where to find any information about clojure development stack? I have hard time finding information what is a good development stack for clojure and where to find additional infomation.

At work I am using following stack:

- ClojureScript at the front. UI with reagent-material-ui and of course reagent.
- Clojure at the backend. Data travels through compojure-api validation with prismatic schema etc.
- CouchDb to hold data.

The stack was meant to be easy to learn and avoid data conversions.

What other other stacks there are for the web development and how to find information about them?
Any suggestions are appreachiated or even hint how to run search queries to find the information.

Comment: This is a really open-ended question... there's tons of options, like Om or Rum on the frontend, re-frame for a popular take on reagent, any database you want can be on the back end.  Maybe look into Arachne, into bidi and yada...  See Web Development With Clojure for an idea of some more of the options. https://pragprog.com/book/dswdcloj/web-development-with-clojure

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am curious, is there a website, blog or even an article which would go through different stacks? Why reagent? Why no sql or sql database with clojure? Which libraries have been abandoned and which have bright future ahead?

Comment: I can find language specific information from the website but additonal libraries evade my sight. Where or how can I find them?

Comment: I don't know of a comprehensive overview, but the author of the book I linked also maintains the Luminus template, which has built-in support for tons of databases, servers, etc. and is super well maintained, so that will give you a good idea of a bunch of options you can just plug in. http://www.luminusweb.net --- another stack you might check out is edge. https://juxt.pro/blog/posts/edge.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't look for a single stack - it is the wrong approach with Clojure and clojurescript. A better approach is to look for key libraries to address specific needs you have and roll your own. This has the benefit of avoiding boilerplate code overhead, but also ahs the disadvantage of putting more pressure on you to try out different libraries to find the ones which fit best with your workflow or way of thinking.

having said all of that, I find it vary useful to 'play' with some of the proposed stacks, just to get a feel and ideas. When it comes to actually building something, I usually roll my own, cherry picking the bits which best suit what it is I need to do. For example, if I'm doing a vary simple app with emphasis on front end rendering, I might just use reagent. However, if my app will have complex interactions with a bac-end server and maintaining state and consistency is going to be a challenge, I might use re-frame or om-next.

At the base level, I think it is good to be familiar with the following libraries

- ring
- compojure
- secretary
- garden
- reagent
- clojure.java.jdbc

Once you do more and more complex things with those libraries, you will run into things you find frustrating, inefficient or just don't fit well with your workflow. At that point, I would check out

- luminus
- re-frame
- untangled

which will give you some good ideas and show you how others have addressed some of the common challenges. I also think the following libs are well worth looking at

- hugsql and yesql
- buddy
- immutant
- cljs-ajax
- clojure.spec

I'm also looking forward to seeing more fro arachne.

Comment: Thank you for good answer. This is something I were looking for.